# Backward Chaining in Protege 5

Tags: ontology, protege, rule-engine, inference, swrl

I was wondering if there is a way to implement backward chaining in Protege(5) using any plugin.
The likes of Jesstab and Algernon are not compatible with Protege anymore and I cannot find any other plugin which is.
Any leads will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no backward chaining plugin for the latest version of Protege. Implement your own plugin that supports backward chaining. The code is open source, documentation about plugin development is also online.